# the secondary page can't read javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using PHP language, and trying to load another page using javascript like this bellow..

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#form').load('http://localhost/project1_5/form/gudang/add-in/php/load.php');
})
</script>
<div id='form'></div>
```

the load.php is like this,

```
<script>
$('#teks').keypress(function(e){
if(e.which === 13){
alert('sukses');
}
})
</script>

<input id='teks' type='text'/>
```

but, the alert doesn't shown..
anybody can help?

Comment: Any errors in the console? jQuery included?

Comment: I've been include the jquery, how to check jquery or js error?

Comment: You can check for any error in the console.

Comment: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Comment: The shortcut to bring up the console is usually the F12 key. If that doesnt work, google "how to open the developer console in X" where X is the name of your browser. (If you see no errors, take a look at the Network tab on the console. Especially after applying the XHR filter)

Comment: GET 
XHR 
http://localhost/project1_5/form/gudang/add-in/php/load.php

Comment: If you visit that link, do you see anything or is there an error?

Comment: it was fine, and nothing bad

Answer (score -1):

```
<input id='teks' type='text'/>
```

Look the "id" attribute...

I don't know why must i answer the question like that.=_=!

Comment: sorry, I am make mistake here, it should ('#teks')... but it doesn't work

Comment: Good spot but this doesn't answer the actual question

Comment: can you fix it @Terminus?

Comment: But i can make it work. Just make sure the your php and your page are under the same web port . Make sure if appear "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" question.